# How to click on a button and click on it again to close all the content AND how to change image when you go into darkmode using HTML CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

(I will link a code sandbox with all my code (at its latest) to be viewed if you want to)
https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-hellman-pyej06?file=/index.html

I have two issues that I was hoping to address

Problem-1: I have a website called dirieahmed. ml (the same as the code sandbox) I have a night mode / light mode toggle, however when I click on night mode my logo (the image which is called hello.jpg and is above the face picture) will stay the same which makes sense but looks terrible because it looks like an imperfect white square. As a result, I wanted to change this. Therefore when I click on night mode I want the image to change into the night mode version of the logo I have made (it will be called hello-dark.jpg) Is there a way i can do that? I will link the appropriate code down below but if you would like to see the  CSS you can view the sandbox

```
<div class="image1">
    <img src="img/hello.jpg" alt="something" width="400" height="300">
   </div>

  <script async>
<--!This is my dark theme toggle-->    
    document.querySelector('.theme-toggle-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
      document.body.classList.toggle('dark')
    })
```

Problem-2: On my sandbox, you can view an About me, Education and Achievements and Other content elements, these elements are buttons when clicked they will drop down a content, if I click on about me then Education about me will open then close and allow Education to open. Pretty Normal and similarly for the button called  "Other" but when i click on Other again to reset all the views and make it clean like when it was originally where no dropdowns exsisted that wont happen. Is there a way for me to make a javascript that will close all content from that div when clicked on it twice. (the code of CSS is in the sandbox but Html and JS will be here)

```
<div class="container">
  <button id="one" class="click one" title="click me">About Me</button>
  <div class="list-1 sec">
    <h1 class="content-header-one content">Dummy text header</h1>
    <p class="content-paragraph-one">Dummy text</p>
  </div>
  <button class="click two" title="click me">Education and Achivements</button>
  <div class="list-2 sec">
    <p class="content-paragraph2 content">Dummy text</p>
    <ul class="content-list content">
      <li>- Achivement #1</li>
      <li>- Achivement #2</li>
      <li>- Achivement #3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button class="click three" title="click me" >Other</button>
  <div class="list-3 sec">
    <h1 class="content-header-two content">Dummy text header</h1>
    <p class="content-paragraph3 content">Dummy text</p>
  </div>
  <script async>
        // Instanciate List div's
        let list1 = document.querySelector(".list-1");
        let list2 = document.querySelector(".list-2");
        let list3 = document.querySelector(".list-3");

        // Reset's all views to the default without .newlist
        const resetAllViews = () => {
          list1.classList.remove("newlist");
          list2.classList.remove("newlist");
          list3.classList.remove("newlist");
        };

        // Checks to see what button is clicked and shows correct list based on input
      document.addEventListener(
        "click",
        function (e) {
          e = e || window.event;
          var target = e.target;
          if (target.classList.contains("one")) {
            resetAllViews();
            list1.classList.add("newlist");
          }
          if (target.classList.contains("two")) {
            resetAllViews();
            list2.classList.add("newlist");

          }
          if (target.classList.contains("three")) {
            resetAllViews();
            list3.classList.add("newlist");
          }
        
          
        }, false);
  </script>
</div>
```

Again you can view the result I have in the sandbox (latest) and on the most recent website dirieahmed.ml for real life view

Sorry if I repeated myself a lot and any help would be appreciated though I prefer if you can show me the code as a runner snippet as I am fairly new so its a bit difficult for me to understand all vocabulary but again any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the 1st point, i think you have 2 possibilities:

- Add the image as a background image with css, so you can easily toggle. Normally you show the "light" image, and if the body has the `dark` class then you can show the "dark" image.
- The second idea is to add two `<img>` elements to the page and hide / show accordingly, something like:

```css
    .image-light {
        display: block;
    }

    body.dark .image-light {
        display: none;
    }

    .image-dark {
        display: none;
    }

    body.dark .image-dark {
        display: block;
    }
```

As to the 2nd point i think you should to it like this:

- you have a variable to hold the current open element
- when you click a button you get the "value" vor that button
- If the value if the same as the current open variable, then you reset the variable (maybe to `null`), otherwise you set the current open variable to the value of that button
- Then you can have an update function. On this function you go through all the of "target" elements. If the element corresponds to the currently open variable, you open it, otherwise you close it.
  Something like:

```js
let currentlyOpen = null;
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".your-buttons");
let targets = document.querySelectorAll('.your-targets');

button.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const newTarget = event.target.getAttribute('your-identifier-attribute');
        currentlyOpen = currentlyOpen === newTarget ? null : newTarget;
        updateUI();
    });
})

function updateUI() {
    targets.forEach((target) => {
        targetIdentifier = target.getAttribute('the-identifier-attribute');
        targetIdentifier === currentlyOpen
            ? target.classList.add('your-class-for-open-list')
            : target.classList.remove('your-class-for-open-list');
    })
}
```

**I have created an example for you:**

```js
let openContent = null;
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.content');

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const newTargetId = event.target.getAttribute('target-id');
    openContent = newTargetId === openContent ? null : newTargetId;
    updateUI();
  });
});

function updateUI() {
  contents.forEach((content) => {
    const contentId = content.getAttribute('id');
    contentId === openContent
      ? content.classList.add('visible')
      : content.classList.remove('visible');
  });
}
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

.content.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p> click one of the buttons to show more content</p>

<button target-id="one">One</button>
<button target-id="two">Two</button>
<button target-id="three">three</button>

<p class="content" id="one">Content one</p>
<p class="content" id="two">Content two</p>
<p class="content" id="three">Content three</p>
```

Comment: your first one worked for me!!!

Comment: ill check ur second

Comment: what is identifier attribute mean?

Comment: whats the difference between the open list and targets

Comment: identifier attribute you would need to give to the target elements, something like `<div class="list" target-id="one">...</div>`

Comment: @Aguywithquestions i have added an example to my answer so you can better understand what i mean! ;)

Comment: is it possible you can use my code on the sandbox or on the question to show me because I tried o implement it and it didn't work :)  you can edit my code how u want as long as the same output is brought that it originally had. :)

Comment: also, my content CSS has many transitions I recommend u look at the actual sandbox and the appropriate CSS Please note that I have many transitions to make the dropdown seem seamless I don't wanna lose that ;)

Comment: please look at above messages

Comment: Post the code you have now, which the changes you have made, and we'll try to help you

Comment: where would you like me to put that on the post or? @Boguz

Comment: Maybe you should create a snippet with the whole code and post it at the bottom of the question. Add an "edit" section to the bottom of the question with the snippet and with an explanation of what you have done

Comment: i wished i could upvote but i don't got 15 rep points yet

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of doing this using two elements where one is hidden based on theme. You could make it a photo that you want to change. This way both images are loaded and you don't have to have the client wait for an image to load when themes change.

The way I accomplished this was mainly in css. The only javascript is to toggle the `dark` class on the page. The dark page has css variables which represent whether or not elements on the page have a display of none or block. On the actual elements which toggle, I feed those css variables into them. It is also possible to add animations or transitions to make it feel fancy, but hopefully this small demonstration satisfies your need for modifications to your own project.

```js
const $ = str => document.querySelector(str);
const page = $(".page");
$(".theme-toggle").addEventListener("click", () => {
  page.classList.toggle("dark");
});
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.page {
  --light-logo: block;
  --dark-logo: none;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.page.dark {
  --light-logo: none;
  --dark-logo: block;

  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.logo-container {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.logo-container .dark {
  display: var(--dark-logo);
}

.logo-container .light {
  display: var(--light-logo);
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  Hello World
  <div class="logo-container">
    <div class="light"></div>
    <div class="dark"></div>
  </div>
  <button class="theme-toggle"> / </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:** It is possible to simple solve by CSS, but this is not good idea for the SEO optimization. Better and most simple solution is to use 2 images and add class "hidden", where you will set for this class `{display:none}` in css file. Next you must modify your script to set/remove "hidden" class by the selected light/dark mode.

```
<div class="image1">
    <img src="img/hello.jpg" alt="something" width="400" height="300">
   </div>
```

Another better solution is modify the DOM, replace img element when mode is changed, or change the src attribute, e.g.:

```
document.getElementById("myImageId").src="img/hello-dark.jpg";
```